# How to move from a FormsAuthentication site to OWIN + ASP.Net Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I already have a big ASP.Net project in which all user management is donde through the use of Membership and Forms Authentication. I would wish to move everything to the new ASP.Net identity + OWIN, yet I have no clue about how to do it.

All examples I've seen so far regard the use of Entity Framework, but I'm not using it since I already have a built big database.

Can anyone point me to some resources or how I can move from legacy Forms Authentication to OWIN + ASP.Net identity?

Thank you.

Comment: "All examples I've seen so far regard the use of Entity Framework, but I'm not using it since I already have a built big database." ... Two things: 1) Using Entity Framework does not preclude using an existing database 2) What *are* you using if not Entity Framework?

Comment: a) if you don't want to use EF, you'll have to implement your own IUserStorage. But nothing stopping you from using EF just for Identity and keep the rest of the application intact. b) see this: http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/migrations/migrating-an-existing-website-from-sql-membership-to-aspnet-identity